# iOS swift arrays

Tags: ios, swift

Why is `self.children` empty after I set its elements in `self.children = object["children"] as! Array`?

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class YourChildren: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var children = [String]()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView1: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
        graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            if ((error) != nil)
            {
                // Process error
                println("Error: \(error)")
            }
            else
            {
                let userName :NSString = result.valueForKey("name") as! NSString

                // find the loged in user in parse core data
                var query = PFQuery(className:"User")
                query.whereKey("username", equalTo:userName)
                query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                    if error == nil {
                        // The find succeeded.
                        // Do something with the found objects
                        if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                            for object in objects {

                                self.children = object["children"] as! Array

                            } //end of for object
                        } // end of let
                    } else {
                        // Log details of the failure
                        println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
                    }
                } //end of find object

            }
        })

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
        self.tableView1.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        self.tableView1.reloadData()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return self.children.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView1.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.children[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your process is asynchronous. You need to `reloadData` after receiving response:

```
self.children = object["children"] as! Array
self.tableView1.reloadData()
```